# Is there a way to get paginated reports with OpenX API?

Tags: rest, pagination, openx

I am using OpenX API to integrate with an application. I am trying to fetch report data using /report/run route.

The doc says that JSON report_format is limited to 1000 rows. Is this paginated?
Or is there a way to get rest of the data or the only option si to go with CSV?

Here is the [link](http://docs.openx.com/api/report.html) to the docs.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but did you find a solution?  I'm working on a very similar problem.

Comment: @stinkydiesel I went with the CSV option.

Comment: Thank you.  I appreciate it.